# how to implement circular scrolling on a carousel/slider

Tags: carousel, circular-slider

I am using a slider i found on the web. It works great except that i need it to do circular scrolling. At the moment when u get to the last image, it slides very quickly to the left back to the first one. I want it to be able to keep going in a circular fashion continuously like a never ending list of images but obviously repeated images.

Just want to see if someone can help out with this or at least provide some guidance.

here is the jsfiddle link for it: http://jsfiddle.net/alibaba/KFjq4/

thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Most carousel libraries come with this sort of functionality as a configuration option, which one are you using?

Comment: I was hoping someone who has experienced in this could provide some coding advice as i have just been given this carousel code as setup in the jsfiddle link. Not sure what library it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in jQuery.  You can add a [component to jQuery called jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/) that will do what you asked.  Here's an [example of a circular carousel using jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_circular.html).  [More complex examples of carousels](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/#Examples).